# A Simple equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I don't know why is not working?!!

```
Clear["Global`*"]
x[t] = x0 Exp[y0 (t - 1)]; 
t0 = 1; \Xi = 0.3; \Gamma = 1.33; \Lambda = 0.7; 
eqns = {y0^2 - (k*(1 - 2/(3*\Gamma)))/Exp[y0*(t - t0)] - (\Xi/\Gamma)*y0 - \Lambda}; 
f[t_] := y0^2 - (k*(1 - 2/(3*\Gamma)))/Exp[y0*(t - t0)] - (\Xi/\Gamma)*y0 - \Lambda; 
Solve[eqns == 0, y0]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Solve` with all of your assumptions entered?

Comment: Recommend you write `eqns = {y[x]^2 - a*y[x]*Sqrt[y[x]^2 + b*x[t]^-2 - f] + b*x[t]^-2 - a*f ==0} /.  y[x] -> x'[t]/x[t];`  Otherwise if you run the line more than once, you'll get strange things happening.

Comment: okay, thanks for your hint.

Comment: CA Trevillian, you mean " Solve [ {eqns , x[1] == 1} ,  y , t ]"

Comment: You are wrong. "x'[t] / x[t] == Constant" implies an exponential, not a power law.

Comment: You are right the only solution is an exponential.